# What's the purpose of SupplierJwtDecoder that lazily initialize JWTDecoder

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm going to implement custom `JwtDecoder` used in OAuth2 resource server.

In the research about default JwtDecoder behaviors, I found `SupplierJwtDecoder` that lazily initialize `JWTDecoder`.

What's the advantages of deferring initialization with delegate pattern. It also seems to cause synchronizing problems.

```kotlin
@Override
public Jwt decode(String token) throws JwtException {
    if (this.delegate == null) {
        synchronized (this.jwtDecoderSupplier) {
            if (this.delegate == null) {
                try {
                    this.delegate = this.jwtDecoderSupplier.get();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw wrapException(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return this.delegate.decode(token);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose is to defer the JWT checks until the `SupplierJwtDecoder` is used for the first time instead of looking up the issuer location (or other properties) at the application startup. If you have an application that builds natively, one of the things you are aiming for is startup time, if Spring Security lookup the issuer location at startup time, it would delay it. That's one of the reasons why the `SupplierJwtDecoder` was created.

You can get more detail on the related issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9991

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation and issue link are really helpful to understand the purpose!